# php: Creating automatic database sharding logic?

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, sharding

I did just come up with the following idea, but I lack the knowledge to say if it is applicable to a production application.

We have a web application, built on PHP/mySQL to make it easy. A table in the database are prone to grow large - a couple million of records easily, so table sharding might be an option here.

Here's how I have imagined the process to work:

A cached file contains the a list with the available tables in the database. Each table contains a maximum of a million rows and when that is reached, the cached list is recreated after a new table has been constructed.

Obviously it wouldn't be a good idea to check the number of rows on every write to the table, so this could be done on a set interval, like a week, or daily - depending on how quick every million of data is created.

Would this be a good way to deal with large amount of data and to keep index sizes fairly low?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked with mySQL in ages, but is "a couple million records" really going to tax it?  It sound like you want to look into "partitioning".  I don't know how mature this feature is in mySQL, but you should give it a look.

Comment: You shouldn't have an issue with MySQL until 3-5 million records - depending on the table (indexes, number of columns, etc)

Comment: @Mitch C I believe you may be messing the 4GB limit under Windows with the number of rows... mysql can easy rise to the tens of millions of rows.

Comment: Unless you are already having performance or scaling issues, there is no reason to consider sharding *first*.  Hell, I'd even consider *caching* before sharding, and I hate caching as an optimization...

Comment: @Frankie: I'm talking in terms of keeping speeds within realistic limits of web-based apps.  I agree with you completely that database system can rise well beyond.

Comment: @Charles: I second that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning ahead for the possibility of enormous growth (game gone viral, for instance) you can follow the steps of those before you and go NoSQL.

**[Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/)** / powers Zinga (and is a personal favorite)
**[Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)** / powers Twitter
**[mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)** / powers Craiglist

But you're building a site in *php/MySQL to "make it easy"* so don't **re-invent the wheel on an extremely big problem**.

Don't mess with the data. Go for a proven solution. MySQL included.

Comment: This post is dated and invalid. Do not fall for the "use this solution instead" trap. As *Facebook* has proven, PHP is highly capable of delivering great performance (especially if you use HHVM). As *Pinterest* has proven, MySQL is highly capable of delivering great performance. On Pinterest's blog: "**We intentionally ran away from auto-scaling newer technology like MongoDB, Cassandra and Membase, because their maturity was simply not far enough along (and they were crashing in spectacular ways on us!)**". Don't be a faddist, just do your due diligence as an architect.

Comment: Another quote from Pinterest's blog: "*Aside: I still recommend startups avoid the fancy new stuff — try really hard to just use MySQL. Trust me. I have the scars to prove it.*". While he's referencing a time of infancy for above mentioned solutions, the blog post is from Aug 2015. He still stands by MySQL, and this quote is great proof that you should not just jump to newer technologies. If you outgrow Facebook / Pinterest and need something else, that's a **great** problem to have (and best of luck to you at that point, no one can tell you what to do as you're in new waters).

Answer (score 2):

You should use horizontal partitioning, partition the table by number of records, lets say every partition will have a million records, that way mysql will internally be handling the partitioning, and besides instead of one big index, the indexes would be partitioned as well.

Read more here http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html

Answer (score 1):

With all honesty, I don't think that would be a great idea.  You should look into possibly archiving old data or going to a NoSQL solution like MOngo.

Comment: +1 I do think that re-inventing the wheel and having a query cross-over multiple tables like that (in the end it can run on thousands of tables) will be a PITA in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of indexes does not degrade linearly with the size of the table.  Tables have to be seriously massive before that becomes an issue.  If you are seeing performance problems, I'd start doing mysql 'explains' and making sure all your queries are doing the least amount of row scans they can do.  You might be suprised at what the actual bottleneck ends up being.

So, basically, if you need the data, I wouldnt go messing around with it.  On the other hand, if its something like session data, just delete the rows that are too old.